IterableIterator<[any, any]>' can only be iterated ... '--downlevelIteration' flag or
In a NextJS app hosted on Firebase I have the following code in the file functions/src/index.ts
(i.e. Cloud functions)
for (const [level, lvlCount] of activeLevels.entries()) {
  jsonResult = Object.assign({}, jsonResult, {
    ["Level_"+level.toString()]: lvlCount,
  });
  .....
}

Compiled with :
 % firebase deploy --only functions

All works fine (no compile error) and when run all (Cloud functions tests) is as expected. But when I run :
 % firebase deploy --only hosting

I get the error message below:
./functions/src/index.ts:205:37
Type error: Type 'IterableIterator<[any, any]>' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration'    flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher.

  204 |
> 205 |     for (const [level, lvlCount] of activeLevels.entries()) {
      |                                     ^
  206 |       jsonResult = Object.assign({}, jsonResult, {
  207 |         ["Level_"+level.toString()]: lvlCount,
  208 |       });

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.

After searching I went to see the tsconfig.json file and (following some suggestions) changed:
"target": "es2017"

to:
"target": "es2015"

and then to:
"downlevelIteration": true

But in either case it did not work for me and I keep getting the error.
How can I solve this problem ?
Besides the error, I do not see why "deploy --only hosting" finds something to complain about when "deploy --only functions" has found all good. I suppose I don't quite understand what is happening in the two processes.
Further details:
In fact, I get this issue twice in my code. It looks like the following kind of construct is causing problems.
const activeLevels = new Map();
.....
for (const [level, lvlCount] of activeLevels.entries()) {
  .....
}


This sounds like a bug in the CLI, and I think you should open an issue about it on GitHub. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/

Well, you may be right. I need to dig a bit to see how this can be done. I am taking a look at the link you mentiion.
